# Access list box selected item from the user control windows phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I need to access list box selected item from the user control. How can I manage that?
For example If I have ListBox `x:Name="NewPicturesListBox"` in MainPage.xaml

```
!--Panorama item New one-->
            <controls:PanoramaItem Header="New one"  Name="Pan1" >
                <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
                    <ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,0" x:Name="NewPicturesListBox"
```

And I need to access them from DetailControl.xaml.cs
The code below can give me the result within the MainPage.xaml, what about other pages, if any possibility exist?

```
                if (NewPicturesListBox.ItemContainerGenerator != null)
                {
                    var contextMenuListItem = (ListBoxItem)(NewPicturesListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(((MenuItem)sender).DataContext));
                    if (contextMenuListItem != null)
                    {
                        var selectedPicture = (contextMenuListItem).Content as Picture;
```

Comment: How are you adding items to the `ListBox`? With a binding (using DataTemplate for TextBox in XAML) or by code? Can you post some more code?

Comment: With a binding  `<ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,0" x:Name="NewPicturesListBox" 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding NewPictures}" 
                       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
      </DataTemplate>     
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                   </ListBox>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have in you ViewModel and Property, lets call it selectedPicture that will hold the selectedValue, and bind to it from your XAML :

```
   <ComboBox Name="NewPicturesListBox" MinWidth="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfPictures}" 
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                  SelectedValue ="{Binding Path=SelectedPicture}"  Width="141" />
```

Comment: Just make sure you use twoway binding on a selected property of a listbox, else some events will not replicate.   -  SelectedValue ="{Binding Path=SelectedPicture, Mode=TwoWay}"